# shuffling values in sqlite database gives None

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I tried to shuffle the values of a column in an sqlite database using `sqlalchemy` but using SQL queries.

I have a table `mtr_cdr` with a column `idx`. If I have

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute('SELECT idx FROM mtr_cdr').fetchall()[:3]
```

I get the right values: `[(3,),(3,),(3,)]` in this case, which are the top values in the column (at this point, the `idx` column is ordered, and there are multiple rows that correspond to the same `idx`).

However, if I try:

```
conn.execute('SELECT idx FROM mtr_cdr ORDER BY RANDOM()').fetchall()[:3]
```

I get `[(None,),(None,),(None,)`.

I'm using sqlalchemy version 1.2.9 if that helps.

Which approach can give me the correct result, but extendable to a large database? In the full database, I expect around 100 million+ rows, and I heard `ORDER BY RANDOM()` (if I can even get it to work) will be very slow...

Comment: Are you sure that SQLite guarantees that there's "order" to a column? SQL certainly does not, and I'd be careful to assume SQLite deviates on that. The `None` values look like you have some NULL values in `idx`, but we cannot be sure without sample data.

Comment: Ah! That was it! There were `NULL` values in the column. I'm confused about why SQL doesn't guarantee "order" to a column though. I thought that was what `ORDER BY` does?

Comment: Exactly, but your initial `SELECT` does not have an `ORDER BY` clause, so the following paragraph is a bit confusing.

Comment: Ah I see, I got it. So the `ORDER BY RANDOM()` is guaranteed, but without the `ORDER BY`, there's no order. Is that correct?

Comment: That's pretty much it. A `SELECT` produces an unordered table as a result, unless explicitly ordered. Some implementations may make guarantees about the order in some situations though. For example often in a simple select like that it'll read the table in the "physical" order from the disc, unless the implementation reads the table using multiple workers in parallel etc, so you may not be able to rely on that.